# Data-only notification not received on react native iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

Sending a data-only notification from FCM to a react-native iOS app in foreground is not received by react-native-firebase/messaging onMessage() method. However it works for an android app and for iOS if we send data + notification message. A notification-only message works completely fine on iOS and android getting this issue for data-only message.

I have used a real device to test this and also tried to send content_available parameter with the payload but that didn't work for me.

**package.json**

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "10.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "10.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "10.0.0"
```

**Podfile**

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

**Payload**

```
   {
    "token":"TOKEN",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
     }
  }
```

**App.js**

```
async componentDidMount() {
        //Get notification permission from user and token
        await this.checkPermission();
        
        messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
            console.log("Remote notification inside onMessage" + JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
        });

        messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
            console.log('Notification caused app to open from background state:', remoteMessage);
        });

        // Check whether an initial notification is available
        messaging().getInitialNotification().then(remoteMessage => {
            if (remoteMessage) {
                console.log(
                    'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
                    remoteMessage.notification,
                );
  
            }
        });
    }
```